# Eclipse cannot see my touchpad CM9 device

Tags: android, eclipse, debugging, usb

I have turn on the MTP settings and update the driver software pointing to the directory of the android_winusb.inf but my eclipse still unable to see the device. Need some helps! thanks.

Code i added in the android_winusb.inf

```
; HP TouchPad
%SingleAdbInterface%        = USB_Install, USB\VID_0BB4&PID_6860&REV_0227&MI_01
%CompositeAdbInterface%     = USB_Install, USB\VID_0BB4&PID_6860&MI_01
```

Comment: Are you referring to the DDMS perspective in Eclipse? Try opening up a regular command prompt and typing `adb devices` , what does that return?

Comment: open cmd from where? My touchpad connected to the com but my eclipse didnt show the device when i click run

Comment: Are you on Windows? If so, go Start Menu > Search/Run > type cmd > run cmd.exe > Type in `adb devices`

Answer (score 0):

1. On your device go Settings > Developer Options > Enable USB Debugging (cant tell if youve dove this already)
2. Settings > Storage > USB computer connection > Change to Camera (PTP)
3. Open Eclipse, Window > Preferences > Android > DDMS > CHange ADB connection time to 90000+
4. On same page, put checkbox in Use ADBHHOST
5. Again on same page, change base local debugger port to 8601.
6. open up CMD and type `adb kill-server` then adb `start-server`
7. Unplug your device, restart computer , open up eclipse and plug in device.
8. Try adding this to android_winusb.inf file , like you did before then restarting adb.

   ;Hp Touchpad CM9

   %SingleAdbInterface% = USB_Install, USB\VID_0BB4&PID_6860

   %CompositeAdbInterface% = USB_Install, USB\VID_0BB4&PID_6860&MI_01

If that doesnt work, i might google for RootzWiki, an android specific site that might be more help.

Comment: still cannot detect my device

Comment: Its quite different than the one you posted earlier.

Comment: Physically trying a different USB port/ maybe the cord is the last thing i can think of at the moment.

Comment: still cannot work. i follow all the steps but why still cannot detect?